# Android - Cant Get Text from EditText and set in TextViews in ListView in Adapter

Tags: java, android, android-layout, listview, android-fragments

I can get the text to set once but after it sets the app crashes and it shows an out of bounds error:

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=1; index=1
```

But i'm not sure why it is out of bounds when I have set a counter and it gets the text then increments the counter.

What I want to do is when the user writes a note on the Edit text and clicks a button this sets the text in a textview, then the user can add another note and this will go under the previous textview and so on. But tried various things and it's not working:

In my Tab I have this:

```
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        final View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab3, container, false);

        final EditText notes = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.editText);
        listView=(ListView)v.findViewById(R.id.list);

        int[] cross = new int[]{R.drawable.cross};
        notesofrules = new ArrayList<String>();

        adapter = new CustomListAdapter(this.getActivity(), notesofrules, cross);

        listView=(ListView) v.findViewById(R.id.list);

        Button button = (Button)v.findViewById(R.id.button3);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                    notesofrules.add(counter, notes.getText().toString());
                    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
                    counter++;
                    notes.setText("");
            }
        });
            return v;
        }
}
```

CustomListAdapter:

```
public class CustomListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

    private final Activity context;
    ArrayList<String> notes = new ArrayList<String>();

    int[]imageCross;

    public CustomListAdapter(Activity context, ArrayList<String> notes, int[] imageCross) {
        super(context, R.layout.item,notes);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        this.context=context;
        this.notes = notes;
        this.imageCross = imageCross;
    }

    public View getView(final int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater=context.getLayoutInflater();
        View rowView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.item, null,false);

        TextView ruleNotesSet = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        ImageView image = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.icon);

        image.setImageResource(imageCross[position]);
        ruleNotesSet.setText(notes.get(position));
        return rowView;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the issue is that you are using the adapter of a listview incorrectly.
You only need one instance of a listview adapter attached to a listview and it is simply the data contained in the listview adapter (e.g. List notes and int[] imageCross) that need to be updated. The adapter populates the amount of cells and their content based on the data of the list view adapter.

In your case when you try to add a second listcell the getView of the adapter attempts to populate cells and grabs data from positon = 0 and position = 1. But since only 1 element was passed into the adapter, it causes the out of bound error for position 1.

Updating data - add a method to access and modify your data in the adapter. Once you have added/removed the data you want, make sure to call adapter.notifyDataSetChanged() to refresh the cells in the listview.

Tab:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    final View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab3, container, false);

    final EditText notes = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.editText);
    listView=(ListView)v.findViewById(R.id.list);

    int cross = R.drawable.cross;
    notesofrules = new ArrayList<String>(); //initial data list

    adapter = new CustomListAdapter(this.getActivity(), notesofrules, cross);

    listView=(ListView) v.findViewById(R.id.list);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter); //set the adapter once, only manipulate the data within

    Button button = (Button)v.findViewById(R.id.button3);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            String newNote = notes.getText().toString();
            adapter.addNote(newNote); //add new note to the adapter list
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); //very important to notify adapter and refresh the listview
            notes.setText("");
        }
    });
        return v;
    }
}
```

Adapter:

```
public class CustomListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
    private final Activity context;
    ArrayList<String> notes = new ArrayList<>();

    int imageCross; //make this a list if you have multiple images and add similar to notes list

    public CustomListAdapter(Activity context, ArrayList<String> notes, int imageCross) {
        super(context, R.layout.item,notes);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        this.context=context;
        this.notes = notes;
        this.imageCross = imageCross;
    }

    public View getView(final int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater=context.getLayoutInflater();
        View rowView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.item, null,false);

        TextView ruleNotesSet = rowView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        ImageView image = rowView.findViewById(R.id.icon);

        image.setImageResource(imageCross);
        ruleNotesSet.setText(notes.get(position));
        return rowView;
    }

    public void addNote(String data) {
        notes.add(data);
    }
}
```